# How to power 24 7-segment displays with Arduino?

Tags: arduino, shift-register, 7segmentdisplay

I'm working on an Arduino project where I need to power 24 7-segment displays (model Kingbright SC56-11YWA).

I decided to control them using 8 bit shift registers (model 74LS164N). This is working fine for one prototype. But already I notice that the segments are brighter when there are only two lit up as opposed to all 7.

Will an [Arduino](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Arduino_compatibles#Official_Arduino_versions) (Mega) be able to handle this when I connect all 24? Or is it OK if I use an external 5 V power source (converted from AC) for all the shift registers?

There's a 220 ohm (around that number) resistor connected at the 7 segment GND. I suppose decreasing that number or eventually omitting the resistor, would also do something, but maybe not enough for 24 of them.

I hope my question is clear.

[image: The setup for one display]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to drive this very easily with nothing but the Arduino Mega and 8 resistors, so you don't necessarily need 24(!) shift registers.  You won't be driving all of them at once, you'll be driving one of them at a time.  But it will be the simplest to build and take no extra chips.  In all, you'll probably need 32 of your pins, but the Mega has no shortage of pins.

Remember that each of the IO pins is tristate.  Putting them into input mode puts them into high impedance mode, which is like putting a very high-value resistor on that pin, essentially removing its effect from the circuit.  By wiring each of the common cathode pins to IO pins and setting all of them to input, you can then set single pins to output low (connecting it to ground) and drive a single digit at a time.  Then all you need is a timer and cycle through each of the digits.

The only thing to consider here is how much current you're sourcing and sinking through the MCU.  But for only 8 LEDs at a time, I think it should be OK, depending on how much current they like and what else you're powering with the MCU.  I tend to go for designs with fewer external components, so this is the solution that appeals to me.

Also, the others are right in saying that a single current limiting resistor on the cathode is not sufficient.  Your brightness problem is either related to this, or to the amount of current your shift registers can source.

Comment: Wait a minute, how do I address the individual pins of the 7 segment displays in your scenario, if only the common cathode pins are connected? Where do I connect that second single pin?

Also, this will be for a piece of furniture which already has an electrical circuit, so drawing from an external power source   isn't a problem.
So I'm also wondering, what if I just do it like my original plan, power them all with shift registers and no multiplexing, but making sure the external current I give to the shift registers has enough ampere? Given that I can draw it from AC, I can provide 3.4A

Comment: Oh, okay, I get it, the 7 extra pins are connected to all of the 7 segments and changing the state of the cathode pin selects which one you're powering. This powers 7 leds any given time, why would I need a peak for that, @stevenh?

Comment: He might be right about the peak current, but I've done similar things before with no trouble, though not on this scale.  But now that I think of it, the segments will be lit at 1/24th duty cycle, so they might be pretty dim.  If possible, 2 or more multiplexing groups can be used.

Comment: Typical peak current via Vcc or GND on an AVR is ~200mA. That's going to be divided - at best - across all lit segments, which isn't going to cut it for driving this many displays.

Comment: If you multiplex 24 columns then you have a 4% duty cycle. You won't see much on the displays I'm afraid.

Answer (score 6):

First, you shouldn't place the resistor on the ground side, but one at each output of the LS164. To get 20mA the value should be 150\$\Omega\$.

Next, the LS164 is a bad choice. You want a *latched* shift register, where you can freely shift data without disturbing the outputs. The [TPIC6C595](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tpic6c595.pdf) is compatible with the often (ab)used 74HC595, but the latter **can't supply 20mA to all outputs** at the same time. (The supply current for one 74HC595 should never be greater than 70mA!) The TPIC6C595 outputs are open drain to ground however, so you'll need common anode displays.
(You would also need common anode displays for a low-power Schottky shift register like the 74LS164. LS-TTL can hardly deliver any current, and even **can't sink enough to drive the LEDs**!)

Dimmer LEDs when there are more connected often points to a too short duty cycle when multiplexing, but I think this is supposed to be static. Check the power supply to see if it can deliver the required current. Count on 20mA per LED, that's a total of 3.4A! That's a lot, and may be the cause of your problem. Note that multiplexing will add complexity, but will do nothing to save power; you'll need exactly the same.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.
The power supply is one I'll have to provide myself with AC as source. So I suppose I can provide 3.4A.
I don't quite understand the "latched" part, but I will look up what exactly that implies.

Comment: @Dyte - the latch means that the outputs don't change while you're shifting the data through. Only when all bits are shifted to their right position you give a pulse to the latch input, and the data from the shift registers is copied to the output registers.

Comment: I see.. but the "shifting through" phase, isn't that a matter of milliseconds? The values of the displays won't be updated all the time, just now and then (when pressing a button). So I don't think this is an issue for me? Or am I missing something...

Comment: +1 for pointing out the limitations of LS-TTL and 74HC164.

Comment: +1 "(ab)used 74HC595" People often count on the fact that not all the LEDs will be ON at a given time.. which is bad design. At least add transistor to drive the LEDs, if you must use 74HC595

Comment: @m.Alin - "People often count on the fact..." No, people don't even know about the limitation because people don't take the trouble to check the datasheet. "Oh, 5V out! Great, then I can light LEDs!"

Comment: @Dyte The issue is that without a latched register, as you shift data through, each segment is briefly lit (or not) as the data is clocked through. With a latched register, the outputs of the register stay the same until all the data's been shifted into the right place, and only then are the outputs updated.

Answer (score 4):

### The Common Cathode resistor is limiting the current

You need a series resistor at the anode of each LED segment, not a single resistor at the common cathode.  Here is a schematic representation of a single seven-segment display:

[image: cc]

With your current circuit, you've connected a single resistor to the common cathode.  That will cause the current to be dependent on the number of segments which are lit at a given time.

Each LED will drop approximately the same forward voltage.  For the standard red indicator LEDs in most 7 segment displays, that's about 2 V.  Assuming that you are using a 5 V driver, that leaves 3V to be dropped over the resistor.  Ohm's law says that the current through that resistor is given by:

\$ I = \cfrac{V}{R} \$

or about 13.6 mA.  This 13.6 mA will be constant regardless of how many LEDs are lit.  If you light all 7, the current in each will be 13.6 / 7 ~= 2 mA.  The current in an LED is proportional to the luminosity; 2 mA is barely visible.  To fix this, you need to connect a resistor to each anode of the LEDs.  This will allow for 13.6 mA in each resistor which does not need to be shared.  The current through the common cathode can then be 13.6 * 7, so you'll get full brightness.

### An alternative mechanism

That is a lot of resistors, however.  If you're using through-hole resistors, it could increase the size of your circuit considerably. You can save board space, soldering time, and component purchasing cost by writing some slightly more complicated software.

An alternative control mechanism would be to only illuminate one segment at any given time.  By blinking (or not blinking) each segment at 200 Hz or faster, your eyes will see the average.  Because the LEDs will only be illuminated for 1/7th of the time that they would be with individual illumination, the average luminosity will be less and you'll want to increase the current. Over 20 mA or so, these LEDs won't increase in brightness appreciably so just use a 150 ohm resistor.

Comment: Multiplexing will decrease luminosity. At 1:7 (14% duty cycle) you'll need to pulse the LED with 7 times the nominal current.

Comment: @stevenvh - That's what I said in my second to last sentence.  Just doubling the current will about max out the luminosity for most 7 segment displays, so I'm not sure that's a good solution here, but it could be a compromise that would allow an existing PCB to function.

Comment: I like the idea very much of solving it in a software way (mainly due to my own software background).
I'm definitely going to try this. So just to confirm, in that scenario, one resistor at the GND side is sufficient right?
Thanks a lot for your clear insights.

Comment: @Dyte - You can't do this with just software. You'll have to deal with the hardware as well, and that won't be less complex with software. Hardware is about the same.

Comment: @Dyte, to answer your question directly, yes if you only turn on one segment at any given time, one resistor should suffice, but be aware that your maximum brightness will be about 1/7 of what you could otherwise achieve without time division multiplexing.

Comment: @stevenvh, by dealing with hardware, do you mean also solve the problem with latched shift registers?

Comment: @vicatcu, Okay. Since these displays will be in a dimly lit place, it might suffice. But I'll have to experiment to see if it's enough.

Comment: @Dyte - If you want to multiplex you'll *absolutely* need the latches, or your display will flicker all the time while you're shifting data (which will be continuously when multiplexing).

Comment: @stevenvh Aha, that makes sense :)

Comment: @stevenvh, how about the 74LS259?
http://www.skot9000.com/ttl/datasheets/259.pdf
(they don't have TPIC6C595 at my local electronics shop)

Comment: @stevenvh, here's their list of IC's:
http://users.telenet.be/gotron/pdf/A1_A3_1_22.pdf

Comment: @Dyte - LS-TTL is absolutely out! Don't look at them anymore! It can only source 0.4mA, and sink 8mA. That's even too little for a static display, let alone for multiplexing, where you have to pulse the LED with several times 20mA. (I'll have to check the function of the '259.)

Comment: @stevenvh, then which one of the list seems fit then in the multiplexing scenario?

Comment: Multiplexing is used to reduce the number of I/Os. An 8*8 display will need only 8+8 I/Os. When driving through a chain of shift registers it's useless. You can use the TPIC8C595s to drive the common cathodes successively, and use a 74HC595 to drive the anodes, but only if you add a transistor to the 595's output to pump up the current to the required peak values.

Comment: Alright. But since I'm using an arduino mega, I'll have enough outputs so I can hardwire all the common cathodes, omitting the TPIC8C595s.
So to conclude: I drive the common cathodes successively, with a specific combination of anodes for each display. The anodes are controlled with a 74HC595 which receives external current (provided the current the arduino provides won't be enough, after all no more than 7 leds will be powered at any given time).
Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned by UziMonkey and most others, a single resistance at the cathode is 'dimming' the segments as more segments are to be lit up. The current thru' the resister ought to be more when more segments are lit, and this increases the voltage drop on the resister, which is why they are getting dimmer.
You need to use 8 separate resistors on the anodes, so the above wont happen.

About Driving multiple LED segments.
Use a 5 to 32 TTL Demultiplexer(aka demux, example : 74LS154) so you will get to control upto 32 7-segment LED modules. The 5-inputs to this demultiplexer shall come from the arduino.
Connect all the 24(or 32) outputs of demux to the cathodes of 7-segment LED modules.
Now, The Arduino will drive the 7 segments thru 7-lines, and the demux outputs will select which display is to be 'ON'. Several factors like voltage to be applied to the LED segments depends on the scan frequency of the Demux.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @stevenvh, see the [DayCounter Kit](http://daycounter.wickeddevice.com) - it's basically your project modularized using 74HC595 latched shift registers. We also provide cables to chain boards together and extension cables for the 7 segment displays. I even wrote an [Arduino library](http://blog.wickeddevice.com/?p=142#more-142) for it that handles arbitrary chaining depth. See schematic [here](http://daycounter.wickeddevice.com/daycounter.sch).

**Edit**

As promised, here is the unedited response I got from Texas Instruments to the question of "How much current can each pin sink in the context of driving LEDs, and is there a limit for the overall current that the outputs could sink?"

> The SN74HC595 can sink or source a maximum of 20mA from each output.
>   The limiting factors are two fold:
>
> 1. The maximum current through the entire chip can only be +/- 70mA. This means that all of the outputs cannot sink or source 20mA at one
>      time as this would put the chip over the maximum level for total
>      current from Vcc to GND.
> 2. The second limiting factor is the output voltage under load. This is specified in the Voh and Vol specs on page 6 of the data sheet. You
>      can see that as you increase the current past the last current spec
>      (depends on Vin) the Voh begins to droop and Vol begins to rise. In a
>      logic application this would be unacceptable due to logic voltage
>      specs. If you are driving LED's it doesn't matter in terms of logic
>      levels, but you do need to make sure if you are driving LED's that
>      there is enough forward voltage to drive the LED's.
>
> So you can have individual outputs sink or source 20mA max , but the
>   total for all of the outputs cannot exceed +/- 70mA. As long as you
>   meet this spec you can drive LED's as long as the current draw per
>   output does not decrease to less the forward voltage of the LED.

Comment: I know the 74HC595 is often used for this, but it's unfit. See my answer.

Comment: @stevenh, thanks for the revision and my apologies. What aspect of your answer makes them unfit? The DayCounter boards just route power through the board. One 74HC595 per 8-segments is not taxing from a power standpoint. The Daycounter also provides a 470Ohm current limiting resistor per segment.

Comment: @stevenvh - If you use PWM and only illuminate one segment at a time, it will work fine.  A naive controller which allows all segments to be lit simultaneously will overload it.

Comment: @vicatcu - Which control mechanism do you use in your libraries?

Comment: @vicatcu - if you supply 20mA to all outputs that's a total of 160mA, and the device only allow 70mA, and that even as absolute maximum ratings (not for continuous use).

Comment: @KevinVermeer my library doesn't PWM the segments, that would be pretty sophisticated... I could probably do it, but it would require it to take over the Timer2 ISR or something...

Comment: @vicatcu - You'd need some sort of recurring ISR, but  I don't think it would need to be a complete take-over.  Just a callback in a timer at 200 Hz or so. Though I suppose that Arduino doesn't offer much in the way of sys-tick timers or anything like that....

Comment: @stevenh fwiw the 470Ohm current limiting resistors set the per segment current to about 6mA @ 5V operating voltage (and it is decently bright). Display is Lite-On LTD-6410G. I've also inquired with TI for clarification on their datasheet and will post back what I learn.

Comment: @stevenvh I updated my answer with feedback from TI in case you're interested, and the DayCounter operates well within the described limitations

Comment: @vitatcu - That clearly confirms what we already knew from the datasheet. Thanks for the notification.

Comment: @stevenvh I guess my point was that you don't have to supply 20mA to a segment to illuminate it adequately either; the 74HC595 is a fine choice for driving LEDs so long as you design within the constraints of its capabilities. The TPIC6C595 is over 4x the cost at volume 1000. So if someone is doing a one-off design fine... otherwise you have to consider the cost element as well

Answer (score 0):

I have several projects that use 595 shift registers to directly drive 7 segment displays (Thru resistors!). I was aware of the output pin limit of 20mA per pin but unaware of the total limit on VCC and GND of 70mA. One of my projects is a LED clock that uses abacus type rows of LEDS to show the time. The first 595 controls the 8 LEDS from 1 to 8-o-clock. Between 8 and 12 am or pm, all 8 of these LEDS are lit. I am using 220 ohm resistors on each output, which equates to aprox 15mA per pin. 15 X 8 = 120mA! Well over the mex limit. The clock has been running for over 2 years now with no problems.